# How to call a function with selected date in @syncfusion schedule in angular 9?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular9, schedule, syncfusion

[screenshot of calendar view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxcHp.png)

I need to call a function with passing the selected date.I can't find the change event in this module.(like onSelect/onChange events in html).Anyone please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Dear Customer,

Syncfusion Greetings.

The requirement “Binding change event in schedule calender” can be achieved using created event of our scheduler

We have prepared a sample for your reference and the same can be available in following link.

Sample:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/schedule-calendar-change-event-binding

```
onCreated(args): void {
  (this.scheduleObj.element.querySelectorAll('.e-schedule-toolbar .e-date-range')[0] as any).click();
  var calendar = (this.scheduleObj.element.querySelectorAll('.e-header-calendar')[0] as any).ej2_instances[0];
  calendar.change = function(args){
    // Here add your code
    console.log(args);
    alert('Date changed');
  }
  calendar.start = "Month";
  (this.scheduleObj.element.querySelectorAll('.e-schedule-toolbar .e-date-range')[0] as any).click();
}
```

And for further reference, kindly refer the below link,

API link: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/api/schedule#created

Kindly try the above sample and get back to us if you need any further assistance.

Regard,

Vinitha